# Conditionally sorting/mutating items from nested (character) lists into new columns in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, nested-lists, dplyr

I have the following data frame that was created from a questionnaire:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
type <- c("1,2,3", "2", "2,3,4", "4", "1")
ex_df <- data.frame(id, type, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

`ex_df$type` is of class character and each digit represents a type of chess piece:

```
1 = pawn
2 = rook
3 = knight
4 = bishop
```

I would like to create a separate column for each type of chess piece indicating present/not present based on the characters in the `ex_df$type` column with `1` indicating that the chess piece is in the list and `0` that it is not.

The final data frame should look like this:

```
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ id    : num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ type  : chr  "1,2,3" "2" "2,3,4" "4" ...
 $ pawn  : num  1 0 0 0 1
 $ rook  : num  1 1 1 0 0
 $ knight: num  1 0 1 0 0
 $ bishop: num  0 0 1 1 0
```

In table form:

```
id  type pawn rook knight bishop
 1 1,2,3    1    1      1      0
 2     2    0    1      0      0
 3 2,3,4    0    1      1      1
 4     4    0    0      0      1
 5     1    1    0      0      0
```

So far, I tried to convert `ex_df$type` into a list with numeric values using `strsplit()` to then use a nested `lapply()` with dplyr's `mutate()` in combination with `when_case()` but this did not work. I'm having trouble with the nested lists so maybe my approach is not correct?

I searched thoroughly before posting but it feels like I'm missing something very obvious here like a function that I'm not aware of that does exactly this. Perhaps I'm not looking for solutions in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` to do this

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ex_df %>% 
   separate_rows(type, convert = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(type = c('pawn', 'rook', 'knight', 'bishop')[type], n = 1) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
   left_join(ex_df)%>% 
   select(names(ex_df), everything())
#   id  type pawn rook knight bishop
#1  1 1,2,3    1    1      1      0
#2  2     2    0    1      0      0
#3  3 2,3,4    0    1      1      1
#4  4     4    0    0      0      1
#5  5     1    1    0      0      0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun - that was exactly what I was looking for. Easy to follow and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape` to create a binary representation of comma-separated values in `type` and then change the column names.

```
output <- splitstackshape::cSplit_e(ex_df, "type", type = "character", fill = 0)
names(output)[-c(1, 2)] <- c('pawn', 'rook', 'knight', 'bishop')
output

#  id  type pawn rook knight bishop
#1  1 1,2,3    1    1      1      0
#2  2     2    0    1      0      0
#3  3 2,3,4    0    1      1      1
#4  4     4    0    0      0      1
#5  5     1    1    0      0      0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ronak Shah - this worked perfectly as well! I marked akrun's answer as correct because I like to work with tidyverse and be able to trace the steps that lead to the result. splitstackshape is a very interesting package, thanks again for introducing me to it!